# How can I use a style within another style for a button?

Tags: android, button, styles

Does anyone have an idea how to add the style "MarginButton" to the style "bluebutton" or "OrangeButton"? The reason I'm doing this is to prevent double code, is this the correct way to do or are there better ways to solve this?

```
<style name="OrangeButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MarginButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Thnx,

Joris

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Can you show us how you do to apply these styles your but on your button?

Comment: It's working no joris i've just tried it check my update ;).

Answer (score 4):

**Update**
Set your orange button parent to @style/MarginButton. I've just tried this and it's working,

```
<style name="orangeButton" parent="@style/MarginButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="MarginButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can obtain it by doing:

**Buttons.xml ->**

```
<style name="OrangeButton" parent="MarginButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueButton" parent="MarginButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_blue</item>
</style>
```

**MarginButton.xml ->**

```
<style name="MarginButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sure it will. I'm glad I helped, you can accept the answer too (maybe even upvote it).

Comment: I Wonder how to add another style to the buttons. Now we use parent as a link to the marginButton.xml to add the Margins style. How do I add a new other style to this button?

Comment: Well, create a new `CustomStyle.xml`, like the one I created (`MarginButton.xml`) and add to the desired button something like: `<style name="OrangeButton" parent="CustomStyle">` and there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you guys want to use borderless button like me or use two style. Try it.**

[image]

View ->

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateNewAcc"
            android:text="@string/or_create_a_new_account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
            style="@style/textButtonStyle"
            />
```

Style ->

```xml
   <style name="textButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/inter</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:textFontWeight">400</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it changing the parent attribute. For example:

```
<style name="BlueButton" parent="MarginButton">
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton_blue</item>
</style>
```